# void function with pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

This program reads number of students and three scores (exams) for every student, then calculates the average, and then displays information in tabular format.  For some reason it is not working. I have to write this program using 11 functions so it is not possible to change the format, number of functions, or any big change in the main procedure.
Update: I made couple of changes and now I can compile and run it and it displays everything

```
int student_num (const string & prompt);
void scores (int scores1[], int scores2[],int scores3[], int students);
void sum (int scores1[], int scores2[],int scores3[], int totals[], int students);
double average (int totals[], int students);
double find_max(const int totals[], const int students);
double find_min(const int totals[], const int students);
int above_ave (const int totals[], int students, double ave);
void display (int const scores1[], int const scores2[], int const scores3[], int const totals[], int students, double ave, int mini, int maxi, int n);
void header ();
void body(int const exam1, int const exam2, int const exam3, int total_grade, int st_id, double ave);
void bottom (int students, double ave, int mini, int maxi, int n);
int main()
{
    int * scores1;
    int * scores2;
    int * scores3;
    int * totals;
    int students(0);
    double avg(0.0);
    int min, max, above;
    string prompt = "Enter number of students: ";
    students = student_num (prompt);
    scores1 = new int [students];
    scores2 = new int [students];
    scores3 = new int [students];
    totals = new int [3];
    scores (scores1, scores2,scores3,students);
    sum (scores1, scores2, scores3, totals, students);
    int ave = average (totals, students);
    int maxi = find_max(totals, students);
    int mini = find_min(totals, students);
    int n = above_ave (totals, students, ave);
    display (scores1, scores2, scores3, totals, students, ave, mini, maxi, n);
    delete scores1;
    delete scores2;
    delete scores3;
    delete totals;
    return 0;
}
int student_num (const string & prompt)
{
    int students, m;
      cout << prompt;
      cin >> students;
          }
return students;
}

void scores (int scores1[], int scores2[],int scores3[], int students)
{
    for (int i(0); i<students; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the three scores" << i+1<< ":";
        cin >> scores1 [i];
        cin >> scores2 [i];
        cin >> scores3 [i];
    }
}
void sum (int scores1[], int scores2[],int scores3[], int totals[], int students)
{
    for (int i(0); i< students; i++)
    {
        totals[i] = scores1[i] + scores2[i] + scores3[i];
    }
}
double average (int totals[], int students)
{
    double ave(0), sum (0);
    for (int i(0); i<students; i++)
    {
        sum += totals [i];
    }
    ave = sum/students;
    return ave;
}
double find_max(const int totals[], const int students)
{
    double maxi(0); // maximum value of the array
    for (int i=0; i<students; i++) //i= loop variable
    {
        if (totals[i] > maxi)
        {
            maxi = totals[i];
        }
    }
    return(maxi);
}
double find_min(const int totals[], const int students)
{
    double mini = totals [0];
    for (int i=1; i<students; i++)
    {
        if (totals[i] < mini)
        {
            mini = totals[i];
        }
    }
    return(mini);
}
int above_ave (const int totals[], int students, double ave)
{
    int n(0), i(0);
    for (int i(0); i<students; i++)
    {
        if (totals[i] > ave)
        {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
void display (int const scores1[], int const scores2[], int const scores3[], int const totals[], int students, double ave, int mini, int maxi, int n)
{
    header();
    for (int i(0); i<students; i++)
    {
        int exam1 = scores1[i];
        int exam2 = scores2[i];
        int exam3 = scores3[i];
        int total_grade = totals[i];
        int st_id = i;
        body (exam1, exam2, exam3, total_grade, st_id, ave);
    }
    bottom (students, ave, mini, maxi, n);
}
void body (int const exam1, int const exam2, int const exam3, int total_grade, int st_id, double ave)
{
    cout << setw(7) << right << fixed << st_id+1;
    cout << setw(10) << left << fixed << exam1;
    cout << setw(10) << left << fixed << exam2;
    cout << setw(10) << left << fixed << exam3;
    cout << setw(5) << left << fixed << total_grade;
    if (total_grade > ave)
    {cout << setw(2)<<right << "+"<< endl;}
    else
    {cout << setw(2)<<right << "-"<< endl;}
}
void bottom (int students, double ave, int mini, int maxi, int n)
{
   cout << setw(40) << left << "The number of students is:" << setw(7) << left << students<< endl;
    cout << setw(40) << left << "The avg total score (rounded) is" << setw(7) << left << int (ave)<< endl;
    cout << setw(40) << left << "The maximum total score is:" << setw(7) << left << maxi << endl;
    cout << setw(40) << left << "The minimum total score is:" << setw(7) << left << mini << endl;
    cout << setw(40) << left << "Total scores at or above the avg is:" << setw(7) << left << n << endl;

}
```

Comment: Can you please show the line and the compiler error?

Comment: Ehh.  If your teacher told you you had to write code like this, with these exact interfaces, he's doing you a disservice.  Personally, i'd have a `Student` class/struct holding the grades, and pass one *vector* (not pointer, not array) of Students, rather than three separate arrays of related data.

Comment: I know, these assignments are useless. can you help me with it?

Comment: @FKaria just updated the question. :)

Comment: Possibly.  I see where you're allocating space for the three arrays of grades...but where are you setting up `totals`?

Comment: after scores3, in main

Comment: @user2841098: You sure?  I'm not seeing it...  I see where you're defining the pointer variable, but you don't seem to ever point it at an array.

Comment: oops! got you... just changed it but it gave me the same error after i entered the inputs.

Comment: You have `=+` instead of `+=` on one of the lines.

Comment: In your sum function, I noticed you were passing in a uninitialized int pointer. "totals" was never assigned values or to an address, when you try changing it in the sum function. The program won't really know what it's doing.

Comment: just made the changes. now i can compile it and run it but the values and table if not correct. instead of average and ... it gave me some  wired numbers

Comment: You are indexing the scores arrays starting at 1 in the `scores` function. You should start at zero and add 1 to i in your cout call instead of starting i at 1.

Comment: It looks OK - what is the problem you found? Show inputs and outputs vs expected results.

Comment: I was wrong, the problem is with the find the minimum function. of course it will always returns zero! I'm changing it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
for (int i(1); i<students+1; i++)
```

in the `scores` function is offset by 1 from what it needs to be. You are not printing the scores that you think you are, and you are lucky that you are not getting a segfault for exceeding the limits of the arrays.

Comment: Since I want to display the id for each student (1, 2, 3,..) I did it. Thanks, I'm changing it

Comment: Either add 1 to print out the student ID, or subtract 1 for the indexing. Or call the first student "student 0". It has a certain Dr Who quality (like "Prisoner Zero").